# selected class will not set itself after selecting a menu option

Tags: php, css

I have a problem with my selected menu in my php script.

When i am clicking on one of my menu options it wont set the li class to selected.

Im searching for hours now and still i can not find it. Thanks in forehand for the help!!

Here the PHP code :

```
private $selectedmenu = '';
public function set_selectedmenu($set_selectedmenu) {
    $this->selectedmenu = $set_selectedmenu;
}

public function html() {
            $html_menu='';
            $menu = array(
                'test'=>array('optie'=>'test', 'url'=>'index.php?page=test'),
                'test2'=>array('optie'=>'test2', 'url'=>'index.php?page=test2'),
                'test3'=>array('optie'=>'test3', 'url'=>'index.php?page=test3'),
                'test4'=>array('optie'=>'test4', 'url'=>'index.php?page=test4'),
            );

            foreach($menu as $key => $menuoptie) {
                if ($key==$this->selectedmenu) {
                    $class=' class="selected"'; 
                }else{
                    $class='';
                }
                $html_menu.="<li{$class}><a href=\"{$menuoptie['url']}\">{$menuoptie['optie']}</a></li>\n";
            }           
            return(
<<<EOT

<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>{$this->html_titel}</title>
            <meta charset="utf-8" />
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet/css.css" />
        </head>
        <body>
            <ul class="menu">
                {$html_menu}
            </ul>
        </body>
    </html>
EOT
            );
        }
```

Following the CSS :

```
.menu{
    padding-left: 117px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    list-style: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-left:40px;
}
.menu li {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.menu li:hover a {
    background-color:#FF8055;
    font-weight:bold;
}
.menu li a {
    text-align:center;
    background-color:#f60;
    text-decoration: none;  
    display: block;
    padding: 10px 0px 10px 10px;
    text-align: left;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:white;
}
.menu li.selected a{
    background-color: black;
    text-decoration:underline;
}
```

Comment: Can you verify that `$selectedmenu` is `'test'` or `'test2'` or whatever

Comment: i have tried 'var_dump($this->selectedmenu);' and it gives empty strings back, but when i set a property to : private $selectedmenu = ''; example : private $selectedmenu = 'home'; than it does set the selected class to home. Does it go wrong at the foreach, where i am looping through the menu to see where to set the selected class ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean, but it sounds like there is an issue setting the selectedmenu, your loops lgtm

Comment: tried to var dump on the place where i try to set the selectedmenu and it gives empty strings back...

Comment: So wherever you are calling set_selectedmenu is passing in a blank...

Comment: Yes, no matter where its an empty string